Define custom Spline Index OR Rebuild Sample Curve Node
Is there a way to set a splines index or otherwise store an attribute on a spline that can be read as 'curve index' in the 'Sample Curve Node'?
I'm asking because i have a setup where meshlines are generated through a generative sim. The number of meshlines change over time. So after Mesh to Curve, i have a varying number of splines. But i want to give unique index-like attributes to each spline, so when spline number changes, this 'index-attribute' stays the same. I need this consistency for use in the Sample-Curve-Node that uses the Curve Index.
If that is not possible, does somebody know a way to rebuild the Sample-Curve-Node?


I have just added these two screenshots and a testblendfile. It's not that important how the curve is generated, you can kinda ignore that i guess. Important thing is, the spline indices change over time (mainly due to the delete node in the sim). Then, in the 'Curve Deform' nodegroup (again a hack by Erindale) objcets from the collection get mapped on the splines using sample curve and the curve index. And here it gets important to have a consistent spline index.
So my goal is that each spline gets either a cube or a sphere assigned and that this assignment don't change over time due to changing spline indices.


The answer to your question is almost certainly: yes. However, in order to be able to answer the question precisely, it would be good if you could supplement it with a concrete example on the basis of which a precise answer can be formulated.

Thx quellenform! I've just added some more information.
